# Using Excel, is there some type of formula I could use evaluate a list of order lines and determine at an order level what their attributes are?

Tags: excel-formula

I apologize if this has been asked before, but I was having trouble articulating what I'm looking to do in a short phrase, so my google results didn't yield anything beneficial.

What I'm trying to do is evaluate a set of data, in this case, orders listed out by order line, and see if they contain product category A, B, or both.

The data would look something like this:

`Order #   Line#    Category`

`001       1        A`

`001       2        A`

`001       3        A`

`002       1        B`

`003       1        A`

`003       2        B`

What I would like the formula to do is say Order 001 is all category A, order 002 is all category B, and order 003 is mixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have office 365 you can use functions unique and filter:
In cell `E1` type `=UNIQUE ($A$1:$A$7)
That will list the distinct values from column A.

Then in cell `F1` type `=IF(ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER($A$1:$A$7,$C$1:$C$7=$E1)))>1,"mixed",INDEX($C$1:$C$7,MATCH($E1,$A$1:$A$7 ,0)`

This checks the number of distinct values (rows as a result of the filter) in column C if the value in column A matches the value in column E.
If there's multiple hits, it says "mixed" else it matches the value from column E in column A and returns the value in column C if it matches.

PS  I didn't text run it, since I'm on my phone.